# Dynamically changing attribute in PHP

Tags: php, oop, attributes

I have some abstract knowledge of OOP but this is the first time I am trying to code some OOP in PHP. I want to create a class that will have some attributes from construction but some attributes that dynamically change.

I am a little confused about all the terms (objects, classes, methods,...) so I do not know exactly what to search for. I made a simplified example below.

This is where I declared my class, that will accept 2 parameters on construction and calculate the third one, which is the higher number (please ignore that I don't check the type).

```
class test{
  public function __construct($p1, $p2){
    $this->p1 = $p1;
    $this->p2 = $p2;
    $this->p_max = max(array($this->p1, $this->p2));
  }
}
```

Then I initialize the object and check the *p_max*:

```
$test = new test(1,2);
echo $test->p_max; // Prints 2
```

But if I change *p1* and *p2*, the *p_max* won't change:

```
$test->p1 = 3;
$test->p2 = 4;
echo $test->p_max; // Prints 2 (I want 4)
```

How should I define the *p_max* inside my class to update every time I change *p1* or *p2*? Is there a way without turning *p_max* into a method?

Comment: you have a typo in your constructor `max(array($this->p1, $this->p2)` is missing  a closing `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this, using the magic `__get` method, which will be called, if a property of a class is accessed, but not defined. This is pretty hacky in my opinion, but works just as you want it to.

```
<?php
class test {
    public function __construct($p1, $p2) {
        $this->p1 = $p1;
        $this->p2 = $p2;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if ('p_max' === $name) {
            return max(array($this->p1, $this->p2));
        }
    }
}

$test = new test(1,2);
echo $test->p_max; // Prints 2

$test->p1 = 3;
$test->p2 = 4;
echo $test->p_max; // Prints 4
```

Doing it this way, the max value will be calculated every time, you access this property.

**Edit:** Because the __get method will only be called for a property, which is not defined in the class itself, this wont work, if you assign the variable a value in the constructor or create it as property.

**Edit2:** I´d like to point out - again - that it´s pretty hacky to do it this way. For a way cleaner way, go with AbraCadaver´s answer. That´s how I personally would do it, too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use a magic method, just a method that returns the calculated value:

```
class test{
  public function __construct($p1, $p2){
    $this->p1 = $p1;
    $this->p2 = $p2;
  }    

  public function p_max() {
    return max($this->p1, $this->p2);
  }
}

$test->p1 = 3;
$test->p2 = 4;
echo $test->p_max(); // call method
```

You can also accept optional arguments to `p_max()` to set new values and return the calculated value:

```
class test{
  public function __construct($p1, $p2){
    $this->p1 = $p1;
    $this->p2 = $p2;
  }    

  public function p_max($p1=null, $p2=null) {
    $this->p1 = $p1 ?? $this->p1;
    $this->p2 = $p2 ?? $this->p2;

    return max($this->p1, $this->p2);
  }
}

echo $test->p_max(3, 4); // call method
```

Also notice that `max` accepts multiple arguments so you don't have to specify an array.